# How to separate and store hours and minutes from 3.875 hours

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm trying to calculate time from distance and speed.
Ie 155 km traveled at 40 km/h. That makes 3.875 hours. But I need that displayed as HH:MM.

How do I convert 3.875 hours into HH and MM?

```
double kmNumber = [Input1.text doubleValue];   // 155
double kmHourNumber = [Input3.text doubleValue];   // 40

double hoursAndMinutes = number1 / number3;  // 3,875
[display setText:@"If you travel %f at %f you would use %f.", kmNumber, kmHourNumber, hoursAndMinutes];
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
int hours = (int)hoursAndMinutes;   // the integer part is the hours
int minutes = (hoursAndMinutes-hours)*60;   // the fractional part of an hour

NSLog(@"HH:MM = %02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should never do manual date & time calculations like this. NSDateComponents was created exactly for this.

Comment: I would use NSDateComponents if we had an NSDate, but here we have a time interval in hours.  Of course the hours can be converted to seconds to create an NSTimeInterval and then converted to NSDate relative to midnight on some arbitrary day and then use NSDateComponents to get hours and minutes from that.  But that is rather inefficient and has as many assumptions as my code does (I'm assuming there are 60 minutes in an hour).

Answer (score 1):

Use NSDateComponents. Use the following to get the components of the date:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:inputDate];
```

And then just use `components.hour` and `components.minute` to get the respective hour and minute as integers. This is better than the other answer, as it will respond accordingly to foreign calendars where hours and minutes do not necessarily follow the same rules.

Comment: Thanks to those who alerted me to the typo in the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about a time *duration*, not a time of day (NSDate).

Comment: In that case, I'd take the time interval and create a new relative date and still use NSDateComponents.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you please show a few lines of code, on how to use components.hour and components.minute in my code? -I have no experience with NSDateComponents :)